# Difference between PathAppend and PathCombine in Win32 API

Tags: c++, path, winapi

I want to understand what's the difference between those functions, and which of them should I use for work with paths?

For example: I want "C:\Temp" + "..\Folder" = "C:\Folder"

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`PathCombine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773571(VS.85).aspx) for this.

> Concatenates two strings that
> represent properly formed paths into
> one path; also concatenates any
> relative path elements.

[`PathAppend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773565(VS.85).aspx) specifically rules out relative path qualifiers, per the MSN docs:

> The path supplied in pszPath cannot
> begin with "..\" or ".\" to produce
> a relative path string.

Comment: As per document, first parameter cannot begin with ..\ or .\ but there is no restriction on second parameter. In the given scenario, pszMore has ..\. It will work for PathAppend.

Answer (score 4):

`PathCanonicalize()` might be worth mentioning, in case the strings are already concatenated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathcanonicalizea
- for win8 and higher a less problematic "Cch" version is existing (takes a results buffer size value)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that:

`lpStr1`, `lpStr2` and `lpStr3` are three pointers, each points to a different string.

and

`str1`, `str2` and `str3` are three objects of type `std::string`.

Then

```
PathCombine(lpStr1, lpStr2, lpStr3);
```

is similar to

```
strcpy(lpStr1, lpStr2);
strcat(lpStr1, lpStr3);
```

that is analogy to

`str1 = str2 + str3;`

and

`PathAppend(lpStr1, lpStr2);`

is similar to

```
strcat(lpStr1, lpStr2);
```

that is analogy to

`str1 += str2;`

that is equivalent to

`str1 = str1 + str2`

Theoretically `PathAppend` can be implemented with `PathCombine` only:

`PathAppend(lpStr1,lpStr2);`

is equivalent to

`PathCombine(lpStr1, lpStr1, lpStr2);`

Therefore every task that can be accomplished by `PathAppend` can also be accomplished by `PathCombine`, but the contrary is not true.

Therefore as long as you can accomplish your task with `PathAppend` then use `PathAppend`.

If your task cannot be accomplished with `PathAppend`, but can be accomplished with `PathCombine` then use `PathCombine`.

If your task cannot be accomplished with `PathCombine`, surely it cannot be accomplished with `PathAppend` and you will have to use another API to accomplish your task.

The reason to always use `PathAppend` instead of `PathCombine`, **if possible**, is because `PathAppend` requires less parameters than `PathCombine` and it also shortens your code.

If you can solve your problem with `PathAppend`, but you use `PathCombine` instead then the first and second parameters in the call to `PathCombine` are the same and you probably duplicate code and type more characters in your code.

In this case the `PathCombine` line is longer than the `PathAppend` line and this makes your code also less readable.

So using `PathAppend` is always better and more productive than `PathCombine` as long as your problem can be solved with `PathAppend`.

Otherwise if your problem cannot be solved with `PathAppend`, but can be solved with `PathCombine` only then use `PathCombine`.